# Apex Trigger Context Variable

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

Here my code for apex trigger.

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after insert) 
{
      if(Trigger.isInsert){
             for(Lead newLead: Trigger.new)
             {
                 //newLead.RecrodTypeId  //'Give value of record type id.
                 //newLead.RecordType.Name //'Null'
             }
      }
}
```

Why "newLead.RecordType.Name" returns null?

Answer (score 2):

The lists of objects available in triggers only have values for the fields on the object the trigger is running on. No relationships are traversed, only the IDs of the lookup records are included.

Therefore, to pull in any extra information you need to from related objects needs to be queried for.

You'll want to do something like this:

```
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (after insert) {

    map<id, RecordType> mapRecordTypes = new map<id, RecordType>();

    if(Trigger.isInsert) {
        for(Lead newLead: Trigger.new) {
            mapRecordTypes.put(newLead.RecordTypeId, null);
        }
    }

    for(RecordType rt : [select Id, Name from RecordType
                           where Id in : mapRecordTypes.ketSet()]) {
        mapRecordTypes.put(rt.Id, rt);
    }

    for(Lead newLead : Trigger.new) {
        string recordTypeName = mapRecordTypes.get(sLead.RecordTypeId).Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice clean code Lacey. I like your map 'null step' to avoid the additional list loop.

Comment: Thanks, not my usual style of braces but I tried to follow the OP's style. Only just realised he's used both!

Comment: AFAIK, the original reason for the convention of having curly braces on the right and under was to save on viewable real estate. Now that our monitors are bigger we can left-align them since the eyes track code blocks much faster that way. Notice how far your eyes need to travel to read someone *else's code when the braces are aligned right and under. But I digress into a holy war that rages to this day... (http://cboard.cprogramming.com/general-discussions/116139-curly-brace-placement.html)

Comment: Ha ha, I'm fully on your side - we're not limited to 25 line displays anymore! I've always had mine on the new line, much easier to read IMO.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because some of your leads that just got inserted don't have record types associated with them. This is normal. You can enforce that record type selection is mandatory through configuration, if that's what you're looking for.

[EDIT]

Now I think I understand the issue (from your comment). The reason is that since you're in a trigger, the associated RecordType *referenced* object is not available. The RecordTypeId will always be available since it is literally part of the trigger object as an Id. However, child objects (referenced objects) will not be available to simply reference from within a trigger. To do this you need to create a map of the referenced object in question by doing an additional SOQL call WHERE Id IN: theIdList.

From Apex, not in a trigger, you need to specifically call this field out from your SOQL like this:

```
List<Lead> leads = [SELECT Id, RecordType.Name FROM Lead];
```

What just happened there is that the child object, the RecordType in this case, was included in the query and therefore available to you. By default a trigger will not have all of your child objects pre-selected and therefore need to be selected afterwards from within the trigger or class called by the trigger:

```
List<Id> recIds = new List<Id>();
for(Lead l : leads)
{
   recIds.add(l.RecordTypeId);
}

List<RecordType> rt = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE Id IN :recIds];
Map <Id, String> idRecNameMap = new Map<Id, String>();
for(RecordType r : rt)
{
   idRecNameMap.put(r.Id, r.Name);
}

// And finally...
for(Lead l : Trigger.new)
{
   String tmpRecordTypeName = idRecNameMap.get(l.RecordTypeId);
}
```

I did not test this code but I think it look ok.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: newLead.RecrodTypeId statement give value of ids.But newLead.RecordType.Name is null. Why it is? This will be occur only in context of Trigger life cycle(Trigger and Class method that called when trigger is fire). But when we used this statement in regular apex class. Then both statement will fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can't get extra information on the related objects from this trigger. if you want to get more information you need to make query for other objects.

```
List<RecordType> records = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE Id = newLead.RecrodTypeId];
string myname = records[0].name;
```

but remember that you **shouldn't make a query in for loop**. so if you wanted to do it in the right way go for Adam's solution.

Answer (score -2):

Put some system debug inside the loop and check your system debug logs for more information

```
system.debug('lead:' + newLead);
```

inside the for loop and see what is being passed in. You may find that it is null.

We cant really give you a good answer without knowint the rest of your set up.

Comment: In above code i write System.debug("Id:- "+newLead.RecrodTypeId) will give me ids of RecordType associated with lead. But we need name of RecordType so i try to write System.debug("Id:- "+newLead.RecordType.Name) this will return null value.